# R | Not able to Knitr | ‘stringi’ not available for R-3.4.3

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr

Recently I have updated my Knitr markup with below command as PDF export was not working

```
devtools::install_github('rstudio/rmarkdown')
```

Now I can't create PDF, HTML and Word file from Knitr, getting this error

```
processing file: R.Rmd
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  there is no package called 'stringi'
Calls: <Anonymous> ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted
```

Now when I tried to install Stingi then getting error, here the options I have tried

```
install.packages("stringi")
install.packages("stringi", dependencies=TRUE, INSTALL_opts = c('--no-lock'))
install.packages("stringi", repos="http://cran.rstudio.com/", dependencies=TRUE)
install.packages("stringi",type="windows.binary")
install.packages("https://github.com/gagolews/stringi/raw/master/devel/winbuilder/stringi_1.2.3.zip")
install.packages('stringr')
```

Always getting this error

```
installing the source package ‘stringi’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/stringi_1.2.4.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 17916239 bytes (17.1 MB)
downloaded 17.1 MB

* installing *source* package 'stringi' ...
** package 'stringi' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Warning: running command 'sh ./configure.win' had status 127
ERROR: configuration failed for package 'stringi'
* removing 'D:/Program/R/R-3.4.3/library/stringi'
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"D:/Program/R/R-34~1.3/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "D:\Program\R\R-3.4.3\library" C:\Users\User~1\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpGOBUsO/downloaded_packages/stringi_1.2.4.tar.gz' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘stringi’ had non-zero exit status
```

Can someone please help

Comment: The `Warning: running command 'sh ./configure.win' had status 127` suggests to try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36279550/6574038) solution. Look up [here](https://www.architectryan.com/2018/03/17/add-to-the-path-on-windows-10/) what it means to add a path.

Comment: you could try to upgrade R to 3.4.4, if you upgrade to 3.5.1, all packages need to be upgraded and re-compiled.